# How to create a pdf download file in Magento 1 my account custom module?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, pdf

I have a custom module that allows customer to returns the product.
Everything working fine and i want to generate a label pdf to paste in the return box.I tried below approach and i am getting error. I used [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf).

```
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$pdfName = "unique_file_name";
$html = "My Printing Label Goes Here";

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser 
$dompdf->stream($pdfName);
```

Uploaded the [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) library to my **lib** folder.

I am getting an error in `system.log`. The error is as follow:

```
ERR (3): Warning: include(Dompdf\Dompdf.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 94
```

**But** if I use the same folder out of the magento its working fine.

Can any one help me in this to short out please.

**UPDATE**

**I copied the [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) folder in to lib folder**

Answer (score 0):

You have included `autoload.inc.php` wrong way.

Assume  that `autoload.inc.php` *ds located at your magento application root dir*(Example **/var/www/html**).

**Change**

```
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
```

**to**

```
require_once Mage::getBaseDir('lib').DS.'dompdf'.DS.'autoload.inc.php';
```

Comment: no i am located the dompdf package in to lib folder.so i can directly call like that right?

Comment: Yes, you can load it directly

Comment: @Amith Is there any way to generate a pdf file based on html in customer my account area?

Comment: Magenot does  not have default feature.You need to build own code

Comment: $dompdf->stream($pdfName);` able to give u pdf content?

Comment: I can generate the pdf and its downloading, but there is no any content in the pdf file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55961/discussion-between-mujahidh-and-amit-bera).